# Getting warning assigning a const void * to a char * array

Tags: objective-c

```
const void * keyPtr2 = [key bytes];// key is NSdata type
char (* keyPtr)[32] = keyPtr2;
```

> warning:***Initializing 'char (*)[32]' with an expression of type 'const void *' discards qualifiers***.

What should I do?

Comment: Try `const char (* keyPtr)[32]`

Comment: oh,thanks,it's worked, you are good man,happy everyday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
const void * keyPtr2 = [key bytes];// key is NSdata type
const char (* keyPtr)[32] = keyPtr2;
```